# Convert mysqlcodes to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it usefull to convert all my PHP codes from mysql to mysqli?
I mean will mysql be deleted? And is there a tool that converts my codes to mysqli? Or do I just have to change all i.e. mysql_query to mysqli_query?

Comment: Changing `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query` is a start, but you should really switch to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Is it useful?

**Yes**, read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1347953) So if you plan on running your code in years to come, you should consider it.

### Is there a tool?

[This tool](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) if often mentioned but I have never tried it and I think you would learn more by doing it manually. It also seems more complicated than doing it by hand if you're a beginner.

Changing all your `mysql_query()` function calls to `mysqli_query()` is not enough. The `mysqli_query` function requires that you pass a link identifier as the first argument wheareas with `mysql_query` "If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed."

And of course it's not just the `mysql_query` calls you would have to change, but all `mysql_*` calls.